# Why Spring PageImpl contains too many contents ? Can we create a custom Page Impl?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, pagination

I am using Default Page Type provided by Spring.

This is the values I am getting when I am hitting the paginated endpoint.

```
{
"content": [

],
"pageable": {
    "sort": {
        "empty": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "offset": 0,
    "pageNumber": 0,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "paged": true,
    "unpaged": false
},
"totalPages": 1,
"totalElements": 10,
"last": true,
"size": 20,
"number": 0,
"sort": {
    "empty": true,
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
},
"numberOfElements": 10,
"first": true,
"empty": false
}
```

Over here I can see multiple other values other than the needed data like sort, paged and unpaged. These details aren't required as per my requirement.

Is there any way I could limit the data that page datatype contains, like creating a `CustomPageImpl` ? If yes what would be the best way.

I get that I could create a new DTO and transfer the data based on the requirements, however I would like to know the best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for implementing Page interface and use @JsonIgnore for ignoring unnecessary fields.

```
public class CustomPageImpl<T> implements Page<T> {

private final Page<T> delegate;

public CustomPageImpl(List<T> content, int number, int size, long totalElements) {
    this.delegate = new PageImpl(content, PageRequest.of(number, size), totalElements);
}

@JsonProperty
public int getTotalPages() {
    return this.delegate.getTotalPages();
}

@JsonProperty
public long getTotalElements() {
    return this.delegate.getTotalElements();
}

@JsonProperty
public int getNumber() {
    return this.delegate.getNumber();
}

@JsonProperty
public int getSize() {
    return this.delegate.getSize();
}

@JsonProperty
public int getNumberOfElements() {
    return this.delegate.getNumberOfElements();
}

@JsonProperty
public List<T> getContent() {
    return this.delegate.getContent();
}

@JsonProperty
public boolean hasContent() {
    return this.delegate.hasContent();
}

@JsonIgnore
public Sort getSort() {
    return this.delegate.getSort();
}

@JsonIgnore
public boolean isFirst() {
    return this.delegate.isFirst();
}

@JsonIgnore
public boolean isLast() {
    return this.delegate.isLast();
}

@JsonIgnore
public boolean hasNext() {
    return this.delegate.hasNext();
}

@JsonIgnore
public boolean hasPrevious() {
    return this.delegate.hasPrevious();
}

@JsonIgnore
public Pageable nextPageable() {
    return this.delegate.nextPageable();
}

@JsonIgnore
public Pageable previousPageable() {
    return this.delegate.previousPageable();
}

public <U> Page<U> map(final Function<? super T, ? extends U> function) {
    return this.delegate.map(function);
}

@JsonIgnore
public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return this.delegate.iterator();
}
```

}